# Similar and semantic search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine, semantics

I have few issues with semantic web search. I m building application in PHP/MySQL, which will work as "semantic" search engine. This problem generally is really hard, but my situation is little bit easier. I will need to search only across data on my website and only data which i will add to database.

The idea is that somoene search food, so system returns beside food documents also document which contain word Pizza, because Pizza is a food. My website will be really specific, so it is possible to model all this relations (at least i think so), but i expects, there wont be everything. FIrst problem is that i dont know how to save this data to database, i mean this relations, cause it will be N:M relations and it has to be really flexible, cause it will be used for every search on website. It will be "like tree", from most abstract to most specific, for example Food -> pizza -> margherita but also food->vegetarian->margherita. My idea is using triples from semantic web and save all relations as reasoned triples.

Next problem is about user data input. Lets say users will be able to add some "tags" to their document and my app should have connect them to my triples. So if the user input Pizza, first of all my app should suggest him all known pizzas and if he choose margherita, than his document would be connected to pizza margherita, but if he add some unknown pizza, my app will connect his document with Puzza only (higher abstraction).

Later every search query would search best match in my triples model and search related document, is it good idea?

My question is really general, how to design this application, what should be first idea or some first push.

Thank you for any ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to use MySQL? A triple store might fit better.

Comment: Well, it doesnt have to be MySQL, but i would like to have some fast querying storage + it is neccesary to connect my triples with user input data, which i expect to be large amount, hence I wouldnt use some triple storage aswell for them, because i believe that traditional relational databases are faster.

Answer (score 3):

One of quick ways would be to keep somewhere phrases like 
"*Food pizza margherita*" and "*Food pizza something*" connected to category id and/or set of documents so you could perform full text and morphology-enabled search for related categories/documents and show upper/lower categories.

This type of queries could be done using stock MySQL Full-Text search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html or external Full-text search engines like Lucene http://lucene.apache.org/ or Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com